# change color using JavaScript (DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

```
 const box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
 let colorAsString = '#FEC6F0';
 let colorAsNumber = #FEC6F0;
    Array.from(box).forEach((element) =>{
        element.style.backgroundColor = colorAsString;
        element.style.backgroundColor = colorAsNumber;
    });
```

I stored a hex-color value in string as well as a number and pass the variable as a value for css property.
Why this code not work can you explain me...!

Comment: `#FEC6F0` is not a valid number in JS. If you just remove the number thing and only set it with the string, this will work

Comment: You can use hex literals in js (`0xFEC6F0`) but these won't work if you assign them to color props because a string is expected. Just use strings. Regardless of how setting a color specifically works, first and foremost your code can't contain syntax errors. `let colorAsNumber = #FEC6F0;` is a syntax error, plain and simple. There's nothing really to explain here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you edit the style property, it is in the end only a CSS string. So to represent colors you can use formats like: '#ffffff' or 'rgb(255,255,255)'. But you cannot use a number.

You can read more about that here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

```js
 const box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
 let colorAsString = '#FEC6F0';
    Array.from(box).forEach((element) =>{
        element.style.backgroundColor = colorAsString;
    });
```

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: OP is asking why `let colorAsNumber = #FEC6F0;` doesn't work. You simply removed the lines that cause the errors.

Comment: He did the same thing twice. I thought he wanted to figure out which one works.

Answer (score -3):

**It's working**

```
<html>
 <body>
     <p id="p">
       on click change my color
     </p>
    <script>
      onclick = function(){
         document.getElementById("p").style.color = "#fff";

        document.getElementById("p").style.background = "#000";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything at all to do with the question.

Comment: not related to the question. also, color set the text color, not the background color.